# how to get area in qgis 2.6.1 brighton?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area, qgis-2.6, philippines

I'm using QGIS 2.6.1 brighton, and I have a problem in computing the area of each layer.

I was actually working on the map of our municipality and I would like to compute the total area of the residential places etc.

The problem is, it actually just gives me 0 when I compute the areas.

I tried using the prs 92 since I'm from the Philippines, but the base map of Google Earth I'm using has a different projections.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Are you working with shapefiles? Is your residential places projected?

Comment: I would think that WGS84 UTM Zone 51 North would be a good coordinate system, it's also more-or-less compatible with Web Mercator (Google), as for how to transform PRS 92 to WGS84 there's a page http://www.namria.gov.ph/prs92/ that describes it.

Comment: When you say compute, you mean you use the area / distance tool and test the canvas, or you run a calculation and return the result in the attribute table?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need an [equal-area projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Equal-AreaProjection.html).

Like [Michael Miles-Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054/michael-miles-stimson) said, the WGS84 UTM Zone 51 North would be a good coordinate system.

Second, to actually calculate the area, you need to go in the attribute table, add a new column, and use the field calculator with the $area expression.

Hope it helps!